# how to access cookie data correctly?

Tags: php

I want to save order keys in cookies then loop through them.

Firstly I save The order key (which is a random generated key) in a cookie:

```
 saveorderInCookie($OrderKey);
   
  echo $OrderKey;
```

Save Order Function :

```
function saveorderInCookie($orderKey)
{
    setcookie($orderKey,$orderKey,time()+10000000);
   
    echo '<br>current cookie: '.$_COOKIE[$orderKey];
   


}
```

OutPut:

> current cookie: e8c5a1587e6de0cfd653ef0adadc9e88

The Echo Gives me a correct result.

But when I try to access it again:

```
   function getPreviousOrders()
    {
       
        $counter=0;
        for(reset($_COOKIE);$element = key($_COOKIE);next($_COOKIE))
        {
            
            $previousOrders[$counter]=$_COOKIE[$element];
            $counter++;
        
        }
       
        return  $previousOrders;
    }
```

This will gives me another string.
which is always this : i3v90f0nhnactvmgjot4m8lmse1.

Comment: are you generating orderkey every request?

Comment: @rsmdh it will be generated for every time an order inserted in a database. The problem is that even if I saved it in the customer id, and tried to access it from another page like that:    echo $_COOKIE[2] *2 is the customer id* ; it will gives me an undefined array key

Comment: @rsmdh is seems like the value can not be accessed from a page outside the dir that I declared it in. Although its a super global variable

Comment: Although probably valid, that `for` loop is very strange. Is there a reason you aren’t using `foreach`?

Comment: Actually, I’m not really certain what `getPreviousOrders` is supposed to actually do, it appears to just be getting all values of the cookie array which could be done using just `array_values`: https://3v4l.org/teCmI

Comment: Although not a requirement, cookie names are usually a known string, or contain a pattern that can be searched for, because most sites have many different cookies, including lots of junk from JS. Are you accounting for that?

Comment: _"and tried to access it from another page like that"_ - probably a path problem. You did not specify a path in your setcookie call, so the cookie will only be valid below the path of the current URL at the time of setting it.